# How to communicate between projects in one solution?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have a solution in C# that contains two projects. One is Windows form application while the other is console application. Both the projects are set to start when the program runs. I am using the console application to perform some tasks that the user does not need to be aware of so I have set the output type as Windows Form application.
Now after, the console application has done its task it closes but I want to be able to execute it again through my Windows forms application by pressing a button. 
How do I do this ?
Also when I use Application.Exit() on my Windows Forms application does that close both the projects or just the Windows Form one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now after, the console application has done its task it closes but I
>   want to be able to execute it again through my Windows forms
>   application by pressing a button. How do I do this ?

Just use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) with were you pass a path to your console executable.

> Also when I use Application.Exit() on my Windows Forms application
>   does that close both the projects or just the Windows Form one ?

Application is an execution context of assembly, in other words it refers to `EXE` were code is executed. So in your case, it will only close your WindowsForms application.

Comment: What if the Console application runs in the background. Is there any way I can tell it to start over again ?

Comment: @WaqasAli: Process.Start will start a *new* instance of Console aplication, so you will have 2 instances of Console EXE in memory. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the methods you need in your console application are public, you should be able to call them directly from the other application. Just add a reference to it in the calling project.

In fact, If you want common stuff like this, you migth consider placing the common logic in a separate project, built as a `.dll`, and have the console and winforms-projects both use this when needed.

Comment: The idea of dll came to me and I have built one but I want to execute the console application at both starts of the program (which it does automatically) and when the user closes the WinForm application.